# Regular expression, Matching only if substring is in string, and nother substring is not

Tags: regex

So im trying to write a regular expression and for some reason I cant get it to work right.

What im trying to do is match if string1, is in the string, but not string two.

Examples

```
fault            shouldn't match
bucket           should match
fault bucket     shouldn't match
bucket fault     shouldn't match
true bucket      should match
bucket true      should match
```

The closet so far I have been able to come is this...this will match anytime there is bucket in the string, but will also match if fault is in the string

```
(?!fault)bucket
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use: `^(?!.*\bfault\b).*\bbucket\b`

Comment: @anubhava use `.*` at the end to match the full line.

Comment: If full line needs to be matched then yes `.*` should be added in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this negative lookahead regular expression:

```
^(?!.*\bfault\b).*\bbucket\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8niVhS/1)

- Negative lookahead expression `(?!.*\bfault\b)` fails the match if complete word `fault` is found anywhere in the line
- `.*\bbucket\b` matches `bucket` anywhere in the line
- `\b` is used for word boundary